# What is the real life use case of @Cacheput?

Tags: java, spring

I understand that @Cacheput calls the method no matter what and updates the result in the cache? Then why do we need this annotation in the first place if the method is called everytime?

Answer (score 3):

Consider an API that would simply return certain data from a database using `@Cacheable` annotation. And if another api would update the same data in the primary data source, it would also need to update it in the cache. Here for 2nd API, you need to use `@CachePut` annotation to implement that.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Why do we need this annotation in the first place?

That's the syntactical expression, that you are telling the spring container to enable cache. It eventually override any with same key in cache.

2. Real life scenario
   A product-refresh operation, where you want a specific product details to be re-calculated, if any change in price and then store that product in cache for any future reference. @CachePut eventually override any with same key in cache.

**@Cacheput will only update the values that are stale and hence it calls the method every time to update the cache.**

Comment: This is the only scenario I can think of at the moment. thanks for your answer.